Best algorithm for sportstrainer-software
What is the best algorithm for my case?
I have one tennis-trainer, which has same weekly timeslots available for his students. His timeslots are x hour a day. Say mo-fr 6-9 PM saturday and sunday 10 am to 6 pm.
The students must give their time preferences (slots) for the week, the number of teammates, they like to have (1-3) and the number of hours per week they want to train, usually one hour a week.
It doesn't seem to be a normal time table or knacksack problem, is it?
Is it scalabel to more trainers and courts?
Thanks for reading.

If every student has preferences about teammates (not only number of them, but also persons) then three dimensional matching may be reduced to your problem
